# query to get orders which has specific list of products

Tags: sql

How to get list of orders which has specific list of products
Here is my table like

```
Order_Id  Products_Id
O1        P123
O1        P124
O1        P125
O1        P126
O1        P127
O2        P127
O2        P123
O2        P125
O2        P128
O3        P123
O3        P124
O3        P127
```

Query to get the List of all Orders which had product id P127,P123 (not only 2 items, dynamic list of items)
Please help me with this.

Regards,
Satya.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY, with HAVING COUNT(*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select order_id
from orders o
where product_id in ('P127', 'P123')
group by order_id
having count(distinct product_id) = 2;
```

"2" is the number of products that you are looking for.

If no duplicates are allowed, then use `count(*)` instead of `count(distinct)`.

Comment: to be sure that the order have both of the product ids 123 and 127 you can use the `EXISTS`clause:

Comment: @Chocolord . . . This logic *does* guarantee that the order has both products.

Answer (score 0):

You can query like below:

```
SELECT order_id
  FROM orders
 GROUP BY ORDER_ID
 HAVING products_id IN (&products_id);
```

Comment: Will incorrectly return orders having only one of the products.

Comment: With this query, if one product exist also it is returning. Not expected output. Both(List of N) the products should exist in order.